# Source code and preg_match

Tags: php

i am new in Php and i wanted to learn codes for taking infos from another site. i looked preg_match and explode.

My question is i wanted to take some infos but there are not tags.

I used this code for this tag

```
$site=file_get_contents("$link");
$price='#<div class="price">(.*?)<\/div>#si';
preg_match_all($price,$site,$pricelist);
for ($a=0; $a<5; $a++){
echo $pricelist[1][$a];
}
```

But in the source code it is like this :

```
<b>500€</b></a><div class=gh_hl1>
<b>510€</b></small></a><br clear=all><div class=gh_hl1>
<b>520€</b></a><div class=gh_hl1>
<b>530€</b></a><div class=gh_hl1>
<b>540€</b></a><div class=gh_hl1>
<b>550€</b></a><div class=gh_hl1>
```

It starts with `<b>` this tag and it finishes with `<div class=gh_hl1>` and `</small></a><br clear=all><div class=gh_hl1>` and also there are another tags starts with `<b>`

I wonder that is there any possibility to take this prices?

And also i looked Simple HTML Dom Parser. But i couldn't find anything. Thanks for your answers...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse and process HTML/XML with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-xml-with-php)

Comment: Use rather SimpleXML or any other XML parser rather than preg_match

Comment: Even regex is cool, `DOMDocument::loadHTML` plus `DOMXPath` are way more cool for HMTL.

Comment: i found like this : foreach($html->find('b') as $element)  -- but if i use this code there are a lot of <b> tag and it takes also this tags

Comment: Yes, use `xpath` instead. not that `->find` thingy, it's trash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could look for patterns in your HTML file. One thing that's pretty noticeable is the  € sign. You could search for that. This regexp should do it:

```
$price='/(\d*)€(\d*)/';
```

And should grab prices if the € sign is before or after the amount (if you guys only ever do it after, then cut that last (\d*).

There are other similarities, like the bold tags, so you could add this for more specificity:

```
$price='/<b>(\d*)€(\d*)</b>/';
```

That's still a decently generic string though, the thing that really ties them all together is the `div` at the end: `<div class=gh_hl1>`. So you can search for that, dealing with the  tag in the process, with this regexp:

```
$price='/<b>(\d*)€(\d*)<\/b>(<\/small>)?<\/a>(<br clear=all>)?<div class=gh_hl1>/';
```

That's my shot. But still that's really silly (and I'm not positive if it will work in PHP, being doing mostly Ruby lately), so let's simplify it down to:

```
$price='/<b>(\d*)€(\d*)<\/b>.*<\/a>.*<div class=gh_hl1>/';
```

Now we'll get all the tags in between. Like stated in the comments, there are a million better ways to do this and probably a parent item above the `<b>` tag will indicate this is a price. Look for those.

Since the major thing we want is the price between the b tags and to ensure it ends with the div with that class, we can make our regexp:

```
$price='/<b>(\d*)€(\d*)<\/b>.*<div class=gh_hl1>/';
```

Comment: if there arent € sign ? for example                                   <b>Name</b></a><div class=gh_hl1>
<b>Another Name</b></small></a><br clear=all><div class=gh_hl1>        how can i use it?

Comment: Change `(\d*)€(\d*)` to `(.*)`

Comment: Updated my regexes so they would really work in PHP, that last one should match what you want, it worked for me when I replaced the euro sign with a dollar (to lazy to look up code for the Euro sign).